# Adding a non-jar dependency to my maven project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'd like to add an XML file to my project's dependencies. I've been pretty successful in doing this but unfortunately I've found that my XML file is not added to the classpath (which kind of makes sense as it is not a jar file).

The reason I want to have the XML file in my classpath is so that I could load it as a resource.

What is the recommended way of doing this, if it is at all recommended?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This solution works for me.  I am using a WMQ table channel file from a Nexus repository.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>wmq-channel-tab-file</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>tab</type>
        </dependency>

... 

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>wmq</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>wmq-channel-tab-file</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                                    <type>tab</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
                                    <destFileName>wmq-channel-tab-file.tab</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <!-- other configurations here -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put it in the resource folder.  By default that's `src/main/resources`.  If you put a file in there, it'll become available in your classpath.

Alternatively, you could modify your pom to say your folder where the xml file is in is a resource folder.  But, I consider this a bad practice *if* your xml file is under your `src/main/java` directory.

Comment: I don't want the XML to be inside my jar file. It has to be deployed directly on the file system so that I can use it with an outside library.

Comment: @user2444735 why? Is it always going to be in the same location with the same name?  Even on other people's computers?

Comment: The XML file is the configuration file for some library i'm using. I can only specify the XML's location on the file system for the library's use. I was hoping I could do that by locating it as a resource and getting its location on the file system. I can't use a constant path because it will be located in different places depending on the environment I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the file in src/main/resources. After that the file is available on the classpath. Then it can be read with:

```
    // Foo.class
    // assuming xml file is foo.xml
    InputStream is = Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("foo.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven uses the resources folder for your project as you mention them in pom.xml. Here is a sample of pom. Anything added as a resource will be available in your classpath and can be accessed in your code.

```
  <build>
    <finalName>Examples</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/config</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```